# How to get the current class name to run mvn test using vim

Tags: vim

I'm trying to add a shortcut for mvn test so I can quickly get feedback (tdd style) when I'm working in java.

How can you get the name of the current class you are working in to concat .Test so I can do something like !mvn -DfooTest test

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are inside the test class itself or the implementation class -- the vimscript below will run the unit test using mvn test (assuming your test class has the same name as your implementation class + Test)

```
function RunTest()
  let src_dir = finddir('src',';')
  exec 'cd' fnameescape(src_dir)
  exec 'cd ..'
  let objName = expand('%:t:r')

  let class = "mvn -Dtest=" .objName

  if match(objName, "Test") == -1
    let class = class . "Test"
  endif

  let class = class . " test"

  echo class
  echo system(class)

  cd -
endfunction
```